# What to do after running fsck and messing up partitions?

Tags: boot, partitioning, kernel, fsck

Wasn't sure how to format the question in the title, but bear with me here. Earlier today, I (stupidly) ran fsck. Now, I get a kernel panic message (not syncing), and Ubuntu will not boot.

After doing some research, I think the problem is that the kernel isn't able to read the partition table or something similar. I tried using GParted, and I get a multitude of errors on every single partition saying there has been an input/output error. It also says that dev/sda has an unrecognized disk label.

I figured I would just make a new partition table (at this point, I don't care about recovering files) using Boot Repair. However, when I opened it, there wasn't even an option to attempt to repair. However, I do have the report from it. [Here is a link.](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/jBprW7z7sQ/)

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell Inspiron 7348 laptop.

Please let me know if there is any more information I should include, and I will do my very best to provide it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182781/97255) came to mind, when I read your post: `When doing data rescue, your first step should be to do a full image of the drive with dd or something similar (cloneZilla is a popular choice).

In other words, get an imprint of the drive as-is so that you do no further damage to the volume whilst trying to rescue the data.`

Comment: If a problem occurs; there is usually a cause; so did you explore any?  Did you check the health of your drive? (eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) which doesn't make or need any change performed for the drive; and lets you plan what you do ahead; as if it's a *failing* drive, a `fsck` is not what you want to do (*ie. save it's remaining health for getting data off it while you can*)  It may also be other components too.. but I'd start with checking disk health unless you know the cause (eg. *someone pulled out the power cable of forced box off in prior session*)

Comment: @Greenonline I had previously seen that post, but I unfortunately don't have another hard drive I could use to do this. Considering my location, it would be impossible to get one within a reasonable amount of time, as well. I was wondering if there are any other alternatives to this.

Comment: @guiverc My drive is fine. All of these issues were caused by running fsck, and now I'm pretty sure it comes down to basically just resetting the drive, but I don't know how to do that considering my current situation.